# pass variable from parameterizedCron to the stage in jenkins DSL script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

```
triggers {
        parameterizedCron('''0 */2 * * * %APPLICATION_ID=41''')
    } 
stages{
    ......
    stage('pass cron variable to this stage') {
    **????How to get my APPLICATION_ID here?????**   
    }
}
```

I want to pass the cron APPLICATION_ID from parameterizedCron to stage as mentiond above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` sign needs to be separated:

```
triggers {
        parameterizedCron('0 */2 * * * % APPLICATION_ID=41')
    }
```

You need to have a parameter named `APPLICATION_ID`:

```
parameters {
        string(name: 'APPLICATION_ID', defaultValue: '1', description: 'Application ID')
    }
```

You can then address the parameter as `params.APPLICATION_ID`. This will be string. If you need to make an int out of it, you need to convert it into int.